# In AWS, we cannot access EC2 instance when specific EBS volume is mounted, why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, mount, subnet, amazon-ebs

I have an EBS volume with all my configured mail servers, exchangers, and webmail interfaces on it. The problem was, we created a new subnet for this instance because it needed a different EIP.

After creating the new subnet, and testing connectivity with a test instance - it worked, we shut down the test instance, and connected the volume that was attached to the old subnet to the new one.

The instance booted up, and we were not able to connect to the instance; not via SSH, HTTP, SMTP, IMAP, nothing. I shut it down, and reconnected the prior EBS volume to the test instance, and it worked.

I reattached the EBS instance from the old subnet back to the instance it was attached to before. And now we cannot access it there either, it just times out when we try to connect to it.

So I built a NEW instance, with a boot volume, and then mounted the troubled EBS volume to /dev/sdf - and no joy. It will not connect.

What is happening? Why can i not connect to the instance when this volume is attached? What can I do to access the volume and at least recover some of the settings we have on there?

Thanks

**Update - Log Output**

```
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Authorization Manager.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Created slice User Slice of root.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Session 1 of user root.
[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start LSB: Bring up/down networking.
See 'systemctl status network.service' for details.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network.
         Starting Postfix Mail Transport Agent...
         Starting OpenSSH server daemon...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Network is Online.
         Starting System Logging Service...
         Starting Crash recovery kernel arming...
         Starting LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems...
         Starting Notify NFS peers of a restart...
         Starting Dynamic System Tuning Daemon...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started System Logging Service.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Notify NFS peers of a restart.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started OpenSSH server daemon.
[[1;31mFAILED[0m] Failed to start Crash recovery kernel arming.
See 'systemctl status kdump.service' for details.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Dynamic System Tuning Daemon.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Postfix Mail Transport Agent.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started LSB: web-based administration interface for Unix systems.
[[32m  OK  [0m] Reached target Multi-User System.
         Starting Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes...
[[32m  OK  [0m] Started Update UTMP about System Runlevel Changes.


CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
Kernel 3.10.0-957.21.3.el7.x86_64 on an x86_64

ip-10-2-246-76 login: [   11.179833] random: crng init done
```

FLOW LOG 1

```
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 29526 143 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 63979 80 6 2 120 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 27737 25 6 1 60 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 62584 143 6 3 180 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 30656 143 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 28222 80 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 31552 993 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 34.201.222.254 10.3.46.14 13029 993 6 1 60 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 32800 8090 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 59625 8099 6 2 120 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 27736 5094 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 28241 8099 6 4 240 1580595489 1580595548 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-04f677fe3abd0271b - - - - - - - 1580595551 1580595588 - NODATA
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 25682 993 6 1 60 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 52807 8099 6 2 120 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 23964 443 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 58486 25 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 34.201.222.254 10.3.46.14 63446 993 6 3 180 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 56520 5094 6 1 60 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 58767 80 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 53051 8099 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 55536 8090 6 2 120 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 25804 993 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 25344 8099 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 23709 443 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 54518 25 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 54403 443 6 4 240 1580595513 1580595573 ACCEPT OK
```

FLOW LOG 2

```
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 7855 25 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 43045 143 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 44203 443 6 1 60 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 45663 443 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 12905 25 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 39966 8090 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 9558 80 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 45535 25 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 12856 8099 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 43378 993 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 13843 993 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 40823 25 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 44662 443 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 43217 8090 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 43565 25 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 9319 993 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 unknown eni-0f432c5f29c9e41f5 10.3.46.14 10.3.246.211 13600 80 6 4 240 1580595458 1580595518 ACCEPT OK
2 068641405600 eni-05a9cdffb1ad2926d 142.93.130.235 10.2.46.58 53434 8088 6 1 40 1580595312 1580595371 ACCEPT OK
2 068641405600 eni-05a9cdffb1ad2926d 219.84.202.20 10.2.46.58 42658 445 6 1 40 1580595435 1580595491 ACCEPT OK
2 068641405600 eni-05a9cdffb1ad2926d 192.241.233.61 10.2.46.58 59033 60001 6 1 40 1580595435 1580595491 ACCEPT OK
```

That IP address of `10.3.246.211` is the one of the device that I cannot access.

Comment: It's quite difficult to say as you haven't given us any diagnostic information, and to give us that information would be huge. Suggest you do some network diagnostics, maybe using VPC Flow Logs, which will help you understand the traffic flows.

Comment: @Tim I have never used VPC Flow Logs - where are they?

Comment: Best to check the **[Console logs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/instance-console.html#instance-console-console-output)** for the OS (Linux) messages. That may provide some insight into what’s going on. Hope that helps :)

Comment: Updated answer with log output!

Comment: They're in the VPC area of the AWS console, you need to enable them. [Documentation is here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/flow-logs.html).

Comment: I got those running too, attaching log now

Comment: Why is it saying unknown ENI?

Comment: Did you change the instance type e.g. from `t2.something` to `t3.something`? Network driver issues are usually caused by that.

Comment: Thats exactly what it was. I never would have thought to look there, thank you!